# How to add a new route to when I already have 'resources: users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes.rb file I have:

```
resources :users
```

I now added a new action in my controller named:  `add_blah`

So I tried this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post 'add_blah'
  end
end
```

This new method 'add_blah' is used only for POST.

```
def add_blah
  render :text => 'testing...'
end
```

I'm getting a 404 not found error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use collection. For member it is using `users/:id/add_blah` route I think. Check your `rake routes`.

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    post 'add_blah'
  end
end
```

Will use `users/add_blah` route.

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :users do
  post 'add_blah', :on => :collection
end
```

This is a bit shorter version of the nested collection/member block variant.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `post 'users/add_blah' => 'users#add_blah'` above `resources :users` in your routes file it will only allow HTTP POST. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I was hoping to do it all in the same block